# Handler as background service

Tags: android, handler, background-process

I am using a library that uses a Handler to handle incoming events and outgoing commands to the server.

```
h = new Handler() {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    //Handle messages here.
    }

}

SocketIOClient.connect(SocketURL, new ConnectCallback() {

//Execute Socket Commands and send message to Handler for UI Update.

}, h);
```

This is the approach that https://github.com/koush/android-websockets has which is the library I am using. And my question is, how do I make this one run or be kept alive for the whole app?
I am currently using it in an Application class for Android but I think its kinda messy since I need to make my methods and variables public for the Application class to reach. Is there a more suitable way for this kind of approach?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use a Service to handle server communications ... and use intents then either by sending broadcasts from/to this service or do any other action

Comment: But the library needs to be running all the time as it is a real-time socket.io library.

Comment: There is a type of service named sticky refer to android documentatiom on Service http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY